Solve higher-order unification problems which are not in $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$
First, let us consider the query pi c\ X c = Y c c..
The answer must be $$ \{ X := \lambda c. H \, c \, c , Y := H \} , $$ for a fresh flexible variable $H$.
However, Teyjus2 cannot solve it whereas elpi can.
I know that the query is out of $\mathcal{L}_\lambda$ so higher-order pattern unification does not work.
Now, let us write an $\lambda$Prolog code:
kind i type.
type f (i -> i -> i).

For the problem pi c\ pi d\ X c = f (Y c d) (Z c c), elpi does not return the mgu.
The mgu is $$ \{ X := \lambda c. f \, (H_1 \, c) \, (H_2 \, c \, c) , Y := \lambda c . \lambda d . H_1 \, c , Z := H_2 \} , $$ but elpi returns:
X = c0 \ f X2 (X3 c0 c0)
Y = c0 \ c1 \ X2
Z = X3

Question.
Can we extend HOPU to solve both queries? Will there be a nice fragment including them? This is a soft-question.

It was just a bug. The current version of elpi solves the problem and returns the right answer.
